# MongoDB locally ECONNREFUSED to connect to server even after locally running server correclty

Tags: mongodb, econnrefused

```
MongoServerSelectionError: **connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017**
at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\acer\Documents\nodejs\task-manager\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:285:38)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)        
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {       
reason: **TopologyDescription** {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
} error!
```

I have started mongoDB server normally which is running on port 27017 at local host.
Even i have tried mongoDB server Service from start/Stop from the services {it was the common problem with people}. I have specified db path folder `C:/data/db`
I'm not using any proxy to connect it.

I have tried everythings seems to be correct but is not working. It was working fine almost a week ago I don't know what happend now. I have even reinstall it after completele uninstallation.

Comment: Did you check the mongod log file?